# How to get y variance explained from a pls model

Tags: r, pls

I have calculated a PLS model with the "PLS" package, and I want to plot the Y variance explained.
I have tried looking through the variable created, but I'm unable to find anything related to it. I can however find X variance explained and total X variance.
When I use the summary function on my model I do see the numbers I want, but I am unable to find out how to extract them so that I can plot them.

The perfect scenario would be if there was a default plot containing both X and Y variance explained, but I don't think there is.

```
library(pls)
data <- (data containing y for Y and everything else for X)
plsmodel <- plsr(y~., ncomp=10, data=data, validation="CV", scale=TRUE, segment.type="random", method="simpls")
View(plsmodel)
summary(plsmodel)
Data:   X dimension: 70 19 
    Y dimension: 70 1
Fit method: simpls
Number of components considered: 10

VALIDATION: RMSEP
Cross-validated using 10 random segments.
       (Intercept)  1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps  6 comps  7 comps  8 comps  9 comps  10 comps
CV           315.5    148.4    121.3    110.7    115.2    114.7    116.3    126.2    145.9    143.4     144.1
adjCV        315.5    147.9    120.2    110.4    112.9    112.8    114.1    123.2    141.4    139.2     139.8

TRAINING: % variance explained
   1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps  6 comps  7 comps  8 comps  9 comps  10 comps
X    86.88    91.50    94.95    95.98    98.19    98.79    99.08    99.28    99.52     99.74
y    79.79    87.86    89.78    92.48    93.26    93.87    94.19    94.40    94.53     94.64
```

It is the last line of the summary I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the summary code like this:

```
pls:::summary.mvr
```

You can get the info like this:

```
# X Variance
cumsum(explvar(plsmodel))

# Y Variance
drop(R2(plsmodel, estimate = "train", intercept = FALSE)$val)
```